# How to connect to the local sql server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server-2005

can anyone please provide some information like how to connect my iPhone app to the local sql server 2005. I tried searching in google but i was not able to find a solution, any url or link will be very useful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: -1 for very general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing that you can not directly connect your iphone app to any data base except sqlite for other data base you have to create a webservice and can communicate to database whatever it may be hope this helps